# Python/Curses: How to write sys.stdout in a newline?

Tags: python, curses

I am trying to working on developing a python theme, which executes the codes that written by the users. And i want to colorize characters if they are strings, integers or keywords or functions, so i thought i need to learn curses library.

The current problem is, the stdout is not printed on a newline, it's printed on the current line and still it gives unpredictable results.

[image: https://i.hizliresim.com/lbEGLk.png]

I'm aware that there's a need to change some major parts of the below codes.
Hope there's someone that gives me a suggestion in order to reach my objective.

Thanks in advance.

**Codes:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
import curses
import keyword

stdscr = curses.initscr()
stdscr.keypad(1)
curses.start_color()
curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_RED, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
curses.init_pair(2, curses.COLOR_BLUE, curses.COLOR_BLACK)
curses.raw()
curses.noecho()

q = -1
KWLIST = keyword.kwlist
code = ""
strings = ""

while q != 27:  # To exit the screen press <Esc>.
    q = stdscr.getch()
    stdscr.addstr(chr(q), curses.color_pair(1))
    if q == 10:  # To execute codes press <Enter>.
        # This scenerio need to be changed later for multilines.
        try:
            # Try adding the string that returned from the executed code.
            # Is it possible to define a newline in here?
            stdscr.addstr(exec(code), curses.color_pair(1))
        except TypeError as err:
            pass
        code = ""
    strings += chr(q)
    code += chr(q)
    for kw in KWLIST:
        # The below regex patterns are working.
        # But there are some problems in special cases.
        # This scenerio need to be changed later to solve this problems.
        regex1 = re.search("[^'\"]\s{}\s$".format(kw), strings)
        regex2 = re.search("^{}\s$".format(kw), strings)
        if regex1 or regex2:
            stdscr.addstr("{}{}".format("\b" * (len(kw) + 1), "{} ".format(kw)), curses.color_pair(2))
            strings = ""

curses.endwin()
```

Comment: If you are looking to replicate something like IPython, it uses readline, not curses.

Comment: Really? Thanks, i am going to look at readline module.